# How long do "quick" pickles last unrefrigerated?

Tags: storage-lifetime, pickling

I'll be opening a fried pickle concession stand in the next year. I want to make my own pickles because I'll be cutting them a way you cant buy from a store. I am using a quick pickle method right now that is 100 percent vinegar (along with spices). I've noticed they fry better being cold. My problem is I won't have enough storage to refrigerate them all. I'll be storing them 5 gallon buckets. How long can I keep them out before they have to be cooled or used?

Comment: What spices? What flavoring agents?

Comment: Please do not use code formatting for text, without manual linebreaks it is virtually unreadable. Thanks.

Comment: @Stephie I have a feeling that this was an attempt to indent the paragraph that got caught up in markdown. Looks like the code used was the four-space code rather than the tick marks.

Comment: Dill seed, mustard seed, pickling salt, tumeric. And I'm confused about what stephie  said about the formatting of the text.

Comment: @DarrellStrandberg : re: formatting.  If you start a line w/ a space, it assumes that the text should be displayed as fixed-width and not line-wrapped  (as you'd do for displaying computer source code).  Your post originally looked like http://cooking.stackexchange.com/revisions/68108/1

Answer (score 1):

When I make quick pickles, I leave them out for a few days (~3-5 days) to get sour before storing them in the fridge. I use a standard, diluted white vinegar solution for mine. If you're using 100% vinegar, you should be fine keeping them out for at least 3-5 days. Vinegar is very inhospitable to pathogens (just make sure that the pickles are completely submerged). Good luck!